# Issue with custom theme resetting when switching between dark and light modes in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, themes, iso, customization, glib

I encountered a problem with applying a custom theme in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS while creating a custom ISO image. Initially, in `10_ubuntu-settings.gschema.override` (which is located in `usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/`), I replace the values:

```
[org.gnome.desktop.interface:GNOME-Greeter]
gtk-theme = "MyTheme"
icon-theme = "MyTheme"
cursor-theme = "Yaru"
...
[org.gnome.desktop.interface:ubuntu]
gtk-theme = "MyTheme"
icon-theme = "MyTheme"
cursor-theme = "Yaru"
...
and other settings related to the theme display.
```

Then, I update the configuration:

```
rm gschemas.compiled
glib-compile-schemas .
```

Upon booting, everything works as it should, all themes load correctly, however, when I try to switch the theme setting type from dark to light or vice versa, all themes reset. What could be causing this and how might it be fixed?

Thanks in advance for the answers!